# hp power supply pinout

Tags: power-supply, power

Probably the wrong place to be asking this, but yet it seems so right...

Has anyone had any experience with power supplies like the dc2100sff's psu?
I would like to know what the pinout of the cpu supp is (3 blacks, 2 brown and one yellow) if anyone knows what these are and how one may be able to mod a cable for a standard psu that be great as  I  am looking at replacing it with a smaller unit, my guess is the brown is fan sense?

Comment: If the power supply doesn't come with a proper datasheet, don't buy it, buy one that does.

Comment: Typically black is ground, and ATX yellow is 12V, Brown is 3.3v sense. But that's not likely it. **Use a multimeter**.

Comment: Of course if it is the supply that is dead and needs to be replaced with a substitute (rather than the supply being repurposed), meter measurements won't really work.

Comment: @chris ops statement of smaller suggests working to me.